# How to run a VBA code when click in hyperlink in a html table on email body

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-office

I would like to call a VBA code (Sub or Function) when user click in hyperlink inside an html table. The body of email is in html format just as a table, attached an image.

Thanks a lot.

[image]

Comment: VBA code currently on the user's computer?

Comment: yes, the email generated with table inside the body with hyperlink is send only to one user and the code will be in his  PC

Comment: Probably simplest to advise the user to run the code themselves. Else you could try [Application.NewMailEx event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) Occurs when a new item is received in the Inbox or [Items.ItemAdd event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.itemadd) Occurs when one or more items are added to the specified collection. This event does not run when a large number of items are added to the folder at once.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well, the body of the message contain son normal text and an html table <table></table> with several lines and in each one a link. In this case the vba code must execute after event ¿click? when user click in any, some or all links but in any case one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook displays and edit messages using Word-light. Its `Document` object can be accessed through `Inspector.WordEditor` (if a message is displayed in an `Inspector`) or through `Explorer.PreviewPane.WordEditor`.

Word Object Model does not expose any events that fire when a link is clicked.

Comment: Maybe the solution is that the hyperlink is a URL that opens a script (asp, php, etc) on a web page host in the local network

Comment: By all means, if you have control over the contents of the website where the links point to. If you don't and you want to control all links in all emails, you are out of luck. Just keep in mind that Office 365 might overwrite the links when it probes external links so you might get a website hit even if the recipient did not click on the link. You can place another link on the website or a form button for the user to click.

Comment: At the end the link will redirect to a php script in the intranet inside local network and the stored procedure execute on it.So i think the subject could be closed, thanks a lot to everyone

Answer (score 0):

At the end the link will redirect to a php script on intranet inside local network and the stored procedure will be execute on it, thanks a lot to everyone